# Distance From a point to a line in Projective Plane

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the distance from a point $(u,v)$ to the line $ax+by+c=0$ is given by $d_\mathbb{R}=\frac{au+bv+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

Suppose instead we have a line in the projective plane, i.e. the set of homogeneous points $\{(x,y,z) \mid ax+by+cz=0\}$ for some real $a,b,c$ not all zero. What is the distance from the point $(u,v,w) \in \mathbb{R}P^2$ to this line? Extending the above to something like $d_{\mathbb{R}P}=\frac{au+bv+cw}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$ is not well-defined since $u,v,w$ can be scaled arbitrarily.

Is there even a good sense of distance in $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Thanks.

**Edit:** Here's an example of what I'm looking for in general. Find the distance from the homogenous point $(4\lambda,5\lambda,6\lambda)$ to the projective line $L$ defined by $x+2y+3z=0$.

Comment: But the points are lines, so I imagine you would want to find a distance between lines. I think RP^2 satisfies some metrizability axioms, so you can define a metric on it. Still, all lines go thru the origin, so that, in some sense, the distance between them is $0$. I think you need to decide the choice of metric.

Comment: Points in RP^2 are lines (through the origin) in R^3. But points in RP^2 really are points on a 2D-manifold.

Comment: Your right. Since RP^2 is metrizable ( as a manifold), why not use the manifold metric ?

Comment: I guess that's sort of the question: What is the manifold metric? How do I use it to find the distance between a point and a line, i.e. how do I optimize the metric when constrained to a line?

Comment: What do you mean by optimizing the metric ? I think, e.g., Urysohn's theorem allows you to construct the metric.

Comment: In R^2 you find the distance from point to line by finding the point on the line that minimizes the distance formula from a point on the line to the fixed point. This of course results in the perpendicular distance. Is there a similar set-up in RP^2?

Comment: I see, so you want some sort of equivalent of the orthogonal projection. AFAIK, the distance function d(x,y) on a manifold M (meaning the metric that generates the manifold topology) is the smalest length among all curves joining x to y.

Comment: I edited the original to contain an example. I'm sure if I see the solution to this, I'll get what to do in general.

Comment: Sorry I could not come up with something more specific; I'll think it thru and will try to get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$ and $u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 1$, the requested distance is 
$$
\tfrac{\pi}{2} - \arccos|au + bv + cw| = \arcsin|au + bv + cw|.
$$

The "usual" metric on the projective plane is the Riemannian quotient of the round unit sphere by the antipodal map. To find the distance from a projective line $\ell$ to a point $p$, interpret the homogeneous equation of $\ell$ as the equation of a plane in $\mathbf{R}^3$, and the normalized homogeneous coordinates of $p$ as a point on the unit sphere.

The formula above comes from viewing (the absolute value of) the dot product $au + bv + cw$ as the cosine of the angle between the point $(u, v, w)$ and a unit normal $(a, b, c)$ to the great circle representing $\ell$. The complementary angle is the distance from $p$ to $\ell$.

Comment: Can this be extended to 3D projective spaces? I mean the distance from a 3D point to a 3D line in 3D projective space?

Comment: @LCFactorization Briefly, no: The arcsin formula (with $(n+1)$ components) gives the distance from a point to a (projective) hyperplane. However, you can use linear algebra to find the (projective) plane containing the given line and point, then use the arcsin formula in suitable coordinates. If you'd like details, perhaps it's best to post a separate question.